# PIP always reinstalls package when using specific SVN revision

Tags: python, pip, package-managers

PIP always downloads and installs a package when a specific SVN revision is specified (slowing the syncing process considerably).

Is there a way around this? Normally pip detects that the package is already installed in the environment and prompts to use `--upgrade`.

My pip_requirements file has the following line:

```
svn+http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/@16406#egg=Django1.4A
```

Thanks for your help!

### Answer

- Must specify egg name as exact python package name.
- Must not use `-e` flag.
- Does not work on PIP version `0.7`, works on `1.0.2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was actually hacking around pip this past weekend and I believe I have the explanation to your pip woes. The problem is just a limitation within pip itself. Due to the way the installation process works the `#egg=[egg-name]` portion must be named correctly to the actual project's name identified within the setup.py's name kwarg (this is the name known on PyPI).

### Short Answer

Your line:

```
svn+http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/@16406#egg=Django1.4A
```

Should be:

```
svn+http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/@16406#egg=django
```

### Long Answer

The install process actually does the following to my understanding (Ian Bicking strike me down if I'm wrong :-P)

1. When it gets your requirement it determines that the link is to a VCS it knows based on the vcs+[url] structure.
2. It checks out the code into a temporary directory within your environment.
3. It runs the setup.py (I believe both egg_info and install)
4. Temporary directory for checked out code is removed from the filesystem

So once step 3 has completed and your checked out source has installed, Django is known to pip as `django` (case-insensitive). However, if you keep your current requirements line, pip will search for for `Django1.4A`. Not finding a package matching that name, it will checkout the source code again and attempt to install it.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! It's exactly as you say - I changed the egg name and pip correctly detects an up to date package. How did you even find this question? :) This is the first time I've had an old question answered. Thanks again!

Comment: I was looking around the unanswered questions because I've always wanted to answer questions on SO but I've been too lazy so I figured I'd start (sort of a new years resolution). So, I randomly found your question and knew a bit of the subject. Glad I could help :-) Btw, not a stalker but saw you're from portland! That's my hometown! (ok that's all :-D)

Comment: Oh the -e flag always updates the repo. That's just the feature doing what it's meant to do. Do you use virtualenv to manage your projects?

Comment: All that's left in my pip_requirements to fix up is `git+` and `hg+` so I posted it as a new question here if you have any more insight : )  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825297/pip-hg-and-git-always-downloads-package-instead-of-detecting-satisfied-require

A fellow portlander? What a small world - I'm meeting up with somebody tomorrow I met on github! 

Let me know if you come in town : ) Thanks again.