# PIP hg+ and git+ always downloads package instead of detecting satisfied requirement

Tags: python, git, mercurial, pip

My other question here [just got answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971799/pip-always-reinstalls-package-when-using-specific-svn-revision/8816608#8816608) about why `pip svn+` was always re-downloading entire packages.

Now I have a handful more packages in my `pip_requirements` file that always get downloaded instead of detecting that the package requirements are satisfied.

They are the following types:

- `git+git://github.com/yuchant/django-jinja2.git`
- `hg+https://bitbucket.org/yuchant/django-storages`

With `svn+` my packages are detected as satisfied regardless of whether I specify trunk or a specific revision. Is the pattern different for git and mercurial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer

When using any VCS with pip requirement files you should always specify using `#egg=[egg-name]`

So your requirements file should contain:

```
git+git://github.com/yuchant/django-jinja2.git#egg=django-jinja2
hg+https://bitbucket.org/yuchant/django-storages#egg=django-storages
```

### Long Answer

If you specify the pip requirements just like you do in your question without the `#egg=[egg-name]`. I'm going to call that string the egg identifier. The problem is very similar to your last question. Pip uses the egg identifier to search the currently installed python modules.

This is what happens if an egg identifier isn't specified:

1. Pip searches for `git+git://github.com/yuchant/django-jinja2.git` in the installed modules
2. Pip doesn't find it so it attempts to install it again

If you use an egg identifier this won't have this problem.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you again. I've written that in my pip reqs file for future reference. I suppose that makes sense as the other lines only reference the package name. Hopefully it helps others as well!

Comment: No problem! Also +1 for jinja2! Have you checked out Flask at all?

Comment: Never used Flask, but it looks awesome! I just went on a 30 minute detour catching up on SQLAlchemy. A frankenstein might be on  the horizon.

Comment: Ya I've moved a lot of projects over to Flask. I prefer the small footprint it leaves as opposed to Django. Also, the debugger that comes with flask via werkzeug is wonderful.

Comment: awesome awesome. Thanks for sharing! I definitely have it on my radar now :)

Comment: Sorry to revive an old question, but this doesn't work for me. `git+https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/libcloud.git#egg=apache-libcloud` in my requirements.txt always downloads that repository, even though it's then not installing it (presumably because the dependency is satisfied).

Comment: Fixed by upgrading from pip 1.0 (Ubuntu precise) to the current 1.4.1